# FS won't create file

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, fs

I want to create a simple console application that would compare two files based on their filename and output the result into a new file.

My problem is that NodeJS refuses to create a new file if it doesn't exist, and acts like it doesn't exist even if I create it manually.

```
compare = (data) -> # data is being read from process.stdin
  fname = "#{data}_compare.txt"
  stdout.write "Attempting to compare #{data}" # stdout = process.stdout
  fs.writeFileSync fname, 'A test.'
```

NodeJS returns `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory` in both cases (when I want it to create the file, as well as when the file already exists).

I want the file to be created in the same folder from where the application is run, so path shouldn't be an issue at all (and indeed is correct in the error message).

I tried to specify `{flags: 'w'}` too, but as far as I know, that's the default value anyways, so it changed noting.

I'm running on Windows 10, tried running command prompt under administrator too, still nothing. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks to me that data, if read from stdin, could contain a newline. Could you output `fname` and check?

Comment: @asaddude it seems that it does. Now I see how that could be causing an issue.

Comment: @asaddude you should post this as an answer. I tried to remove the two last characters (`\n`) from the `data`, using `data.substring(0, data.length - 2)` and the file is now being created correctly. This didn't cross my mind at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable is read from stdin and therefore contains a newline at the end. This is probably what's causing the non-descriptive `ENOENT` error.

You can remove the newline (and any other whitespace that user might have accidentally entered) with `data = data.trim()`

This would be better than the `substring` solution since the newline is 2 characters only on Windows and 1 character elsewhere.

Comment: Good point with the `.trim()` instead of `.substring()` (though the app will be run in a controlled environment, only on Windows devices). Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path exists (not necessarily the file itself, but the folder structure), and that the process user has write permissions.

Comment: The path exists, it's the path where the `.coffee` (and the compiled `.js`) file is located. I tried running it under my normal user account. Given I was able to create files there using Windows Explorer, the process should be able to do so as well. As I've said, I also tried to run it as Administrator. Even then the file couldn't be created.

Answer (score 0):

An [ENOENT](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_enoent_no_such_file_or_directory) error tells you that a component of the specified pathname does not exist -- no entity (file or directory) could be found by the given path.

Make sure you are putting the 'dot':
`'./path/to/file'`